# Jquery dynamic button on click event not working

Tags: jquery

I have created buttons in jquery dynamically but on click functions for those buttons are not working .
Could anybody please help me on this ?

```
<div id ="review_div"></div>

var html = "";
if (Variants.length == 0) {
    html += "<tr><th>No Variants have been specified</th></tr>";
} else {
    html += "<tr><th>File Locations </th><th>View</th></tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < Variants.length; i++) {                    
        html += "<tr><td>" + Variants[i] + "</td><td>" + '<button class="Review_Button" type="button" id="Review_Variants_' + i + '" onclick="myfunction(+Variants[i]+)">View</button>' + "</td></tr>";
    }
}

$('#review_div').html(html);

function  myfunction(var variant) {
    alert ("something");
}
```

Comment: `html += "<tr><td>" + Variants[i] + "</td><td>" + '<button class="Review_Button" type="button" id="Review_Variants_' + i + '"` seems to be error is here in terms of concatenation. specifically here: `id="Review_Variants_' + i + '"`

Comment: Also, here `myfunction(+Variants[i]+)` and here `myfunction(var variant)`.

Comment: In the function params no need `var` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line of code in your for loop (you are missing the quotes around Variants[i]):

```js
html += "<tr><td>" + Variants[i] + "</td><td>" + '<button class="Review_Button" type="button" id="Review_Variants_' + i + '" onclick="myfunction('+Variants[i]+')">View</button>' + "</td></tr>";
```

Also remove 'var' from your function arguments, it is not needed:

```js
function  myfunction(variant) {
  alert ("something");
}
```